# Cocos2d-x C++ vs JavaScript phone app

Tags: javascript, c++, cocos2d-x

I'm just staring to write a game and I would like to use Cocos2d and I notice that, basically I have two ways to develop it. Using the framework, in order to write and phone app, I could write it on javascript or c++.

I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages about using each technology, related to the framewok.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not two, but countless options. You are asking the [wrong question](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/05/the-game-engine-dating-guide-how-to-find-the-right-engine-for-your-game/).

Are there differences? Yes. Mainly the programming language, and subsequently the development workflow.

But what are your requirements? Have similar apps been created with the engine? Which language do you have most experience with, or simply prefer? What are your personal goals, your level of programming experience?

That's what **really** determines the advantages & disadvantages of one engine over another.